# Should I use hadoop map reduce with php to connect to api and write to database

Tags: php, mysql, hadoop

I have a situation wherein I have to do following steps every 15 seconds

1. Connect to an api
2. download the json string
3. parse and apply some logic on it.
4. insert into the mysql database.

To speed up the process I tried to use hadoop, using mapping reducing where

- `Mapper.php` is the file to download the data from api and sent to reducer.
- `Reducer.php` is has the logic to parse and create insert statements for mysql.

This is to save the running time and discover any performance issues, But I see that if I run with hadoop our without hadoop, the entire process takes the same amount of time.

Isn't hadoop used to process something faster than normal operating system?

Do you have any better ideas with less load on server and faster processing?

Comment: improve formatting, clarify question